# How can I search Gmail for a Windows activation key?

Tags: gmail, search, regex

Somewhere lost in my Gmail is a Windows key. It's by itself in an email but I cannot find it. It's formatted like so:

```
XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
```

If Gmail supported regular expressions it would be easy.

```
.....-.....-.....-.....-.....
```

But since they don't, does anyone have any other suggestions? I did try [this script](http://www.labnol.org/internet/advanced-gmail-search/21623/) to search it but it hit a maximum timeout and didn't make it very far into my email (there are a lot of them).

Comment: I have the same issue as well sometimes. I find it by searching for Microsoft Windows Order and it usually pops them up.

Comment: why is this moved to WebApps? This is a superuser Windows question.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Don't ask me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two solutions here:

1. **Google Drive Spreadsheet** - Continue with using the speadsheet as linked, but limit the search area to avoid hitting the "Exceeded maximum execution time".
2. **Download via IMAP**

### 1. Google Drive Spreadsheet

It's possible via a Google Drive Spreadsheet.

The original credit for Regular Expression based search of Gmail emails goes to [Labnol.org](http://www.labnol.org/internet/advanced-gmail-search/21623/).

#### Step by Step

Here are the step by step instructions from the original page modified to match the original questions requirements:

1. [Click here to make a copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aofk8L6brI_edHNzaTY2UXZodHQxbWtQYko3Y2s3N1E&newcopy=true) of the Gmail RegEx sheet into your Google Docs account.
2. Wait for 10-15 seconds and a new `Gmail RegEx` menu will appear in your new Google sheet.
3. Choose `Initialize` from the menu and grant the necessary permissions as requested by the program.
4. The program will search your entire mailbox by default but if you would like to limit the search to any particular label (say `Inbox` or `Spam`), just put that label name in cell `F3`. **In this case if you sent the email to yourself `Sent` might be the best label, see further notes below**
5. Now enter any regular expression in the cell `F4`. **The regular expression you are looking for is `([A-Za-z0-9]{5}(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]{5}){4})`**
6. Choose `Search Mailbox` from the Gmail RegEx menu to begin searching.
7. Wait and wait some more.

In my test case the first result took over 4 minutes to retrieve.

#### Exceeded maximum execution time

You may experience the `Exceeded maximum execution time` error.
In this case I would limit your search by creating a custom label covering a specific time period in GMail before commencing the search.
I.e:

1. Open Gmail
2. Search between 2012/01/01 (Jan 1st) and 2012/04/01 (April 1st) in `Sent`.
3. Mark all emails with label `searchblock1`.

This alternative label (`searchblock1`) should be entered in cell `F3` instead of `Sent`.

#### Other limits

The original article dated July 2012 also notes (although limits might have changed):

> Please do note that Google Apps Script allows you to perform 10,000
>   read operations in Gmail per day.

#### Multiple Google Accounts

Also note that looking at the code this only searches the "primary" user account i.e. `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/` if you are using multiple Google accounts you may want to change this to `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/` etc.

### 2. Download via IMAP

You will need to ensure IMAP support is enabled for your GMail account in settings for these.

1. Use a IMAP client that supports regular expression search
2. **OR** IMAP backup tool to download as a ".mbox" file and search the plain text output locally.

Not tested but Thunderbird add-on [Expression Search / GMailUI](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/gmailui/) says it supports regex searches.

And for IMAP backup the first one that comes up is [IMAP Backup Tool](http://www.tamale.net/imapbackup/).

Either of these could be used with a limited search marked by initially using Gmail to label a range of interesting emails (say by date and sender) and then only downloading / searching those locally via the IMAP folder / label.

Comment: [I've tried this script but it didn't seem to work because there are too many and this email could be months or even over a year old.](http://i.imgur.com/l0gHVZ0.png)

Comment: @Alex note the specific details of using a label like "searchblock1" to reduce the search area to an amount that won't hit the execution limits. On testing my first result was over a year old with serveral 1000's of emails searched, keep the search area small and you'll get there.

Comment: @AlexFord Updated answer to include alternative option for you - IMAP.